# Merge tags [airflow] and [apache-airflow]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Yesterday it came to my attention, that tags [airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airflow) and [apache-airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-airflow) do exist. Not sure what's the convention when creating synonym tags, but there's a whole lot more content tags available, which all start with [airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/airflow) (for it's individual components).

Comment: It looks like [tag:airflow] and [tag:apache-airflow] have been synonyms since Jan 16 '18.

Comment: I've just noticed questions below both of the tags; so it might only be a re-tag request.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be possible...could you link an example that has the apache-airflow tag?

Comment: Some old questions that had apache-airflow may still have it, but that's purely due to caching. Editing will automatically fix the tag, but it doesn't always fix itself

Comment: There is nothing to be done here. [[tag:apache-airflow]] already is a synonym and while there are some [237 posts with that tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1294836) they are still findable by searching for [[tag:airflow]]. New questions that try and use the longer tag are automatically retagged with the shorter tag and if one of those posts with the longer version were to be edited they too would have the tag replaced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters technically shouldn't it be status-completed, then?

Comment: (its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has". See for example *["Weird Al" Yankovic - Word Crimes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc&t=1m20s)* and [How to Use Its and It's](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s).)